# How to install fastai v0.7 in Google Colab?

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory, fast-ai

I have used the command:

```
!pip install fastai==0.7.0
```

to install this but every time I open the notebook, I have to re-run this cell. Is there any way to install this permanently into my notebook?

Comment: Write all install statements in a single cell. Every time you open the notebook, run the single install cell

Answer (score 0):

Your notebook is not permanent,it is ran on a virtual machine that resets itself every 12 hrs, so you'll have to rerun the cell every time you are changed to a new virtual machine.

I'm sorry but there is no permanent solution to this.